# Is it possible to prove this inequality with a geometric sum

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality

I am wondering if the following inequality is true:

> $$\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}x^k \leq Nx^N \qquad \forall x\geq 1$$

I have verified the inequality for different values of $N$ but I am looking for a way to prove that it holds for all $N\in\mathbb{N}$.

Any help is appreciated in either proving this or showing that it is not true. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is a problem here, in the rhs $k$ is not defined. And in the lhs, $k$ is just a sum variable. Did you mean $Nx^N$ in the rhs?

Comment: Yes sorry! Edited the question

Comment: For $x\ge 1$, we have$$\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}x^k\le \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^N\le Nx^N$$

Comment: **Hint:** With $x\geq 1$ fixed, the map $n\mapsto x^n$ has derivative $x^n\log x\geq 0$ and hence is increasing on $[0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true if $x\geq 1$. To see this, expand the r.h.s. as
$$Nx^N = x^N+x^N+\dots+x^N$$
where the sum has $N$ terms. Now, couple each one of these with the terms at your left side, you'll have
$$x^k\leq x^N$$
for every $k<N$ since $x\geq 1$. Now you sum up these inequalities to get your result.

Other way to do it is using the formula for geometric sums. Thus your inequality is
$$\frac{x^N-1}{x-1} \leq Nx^N$$
and I'm pretty sure you can handle from here.

Comment: I can't believe I couldn't figure that out! Thanks though :-)